# Combine multiple regexes into one / build small regex to match a set of fixed strings

Tags: regex, algorithm, optimization, google-analytics

**The situation:**

We created a tool [Google Analytics Referrer Spam Killer](https://www.adwordsrobot.com/en/tools/ga-referrer-spam-killer), which automatically adds filters to Google Analytics to filter out spam.

These filters exclude traffic which comes from certain spammy domains. Right now we have 400+ spammy domains in our list.

To remove the spam, we add a regex (like so `domain1.com|domain2.com|..`) as a filter to Analytics and tell Analytics to ignore all traffic which matches this filter.

**The problem:**

Google Analytics has a 255 character limit for each regex (one regex per filter). Because of that we must to create a lot of filters to add all 400+ domains (now 30+ filters). The problem is, there is another limit. Number of write operation per day. Each new filter is 3 more write operations.

**The question:**

What I want to find the shortest regex to exactly match another regex.

For example you need to match the following strings:

```
`abc`, `abbc` and `aac`
```

You could match them with the following regexes: `/^abc|abbc|aac$/`, `/^a(b|bb|a)c$/`, `/^a(bb?|a)c$/`, etc..

Basically I'm looking for an expression which exactly matches `/^abc|abbc|aac$/`, but is shorter in length.

I found [multiregexp](https://github.com/fulmicoton/multiregexp), but as far as I can tell, it doesn't create a new regex out of another expression which I can use in Analytics.

Is there a tool which can optimize regexes for length?

Comment: Try the _Strings To Regex_ Ternary Tool in [RegexFormat 6](http://www.regexformat.com). See [dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/default_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg) regex screenshot. Just put all the domain names in (with common _.com_'s, leaving the com's off, etc), it will generate a regex for you that is guaranteed smaller. Tweak it as needed.

Comment: I'm not on Windows, but as far as I can see, it is not compressing the regexes, but just making them more readable.

Comment: It depends on how close the you can group substrings. For example, it turns this `aback abacus abacuses abaft abaka abakas abalone abalones abamp` into this `aba(?:c(?:k|us(?:es)?)|ft|kas?|lones?|mp)` compressing it from 60 to 40 chars. It basically creates a full regex trie (which can be called a ternary tree).

Comment: Basically, you need to fragment your regexes. Take a look at this text version of a dictionary [here](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt). If your samples aren't sufficiently similar, this probably wont get the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this C tool which compiles on Linux: http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/regexopt.html

Super easy:

```
$ ./regex-opt '123.123.123.123'
(123.){3}123

$ ./regex-opt 'abc|abbc|aac'
(aa|ab{1,2})c

$ ./regex-opt 'aback|abacus|abacuses|abaft|abaka|abakas|abalone|abalones|abamp'
aba(ck|ft|ka|lone|mp|(cu|ka|(cus|lon)e)s)
```

I wasn't able to run the tool suggested by @sln. It looks like it makes an even shorter regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an existing tool for combining / compressing / optimising regexes.  There may be one.  Maybe by building a finite-state machine out of a regex and then generating a regex back out of that?

You don't need to solve the problem for the general case of arbitrary regexes.  I think it's a better bet to look at creating compact regexes to match any of a given set of fixed strings.

There may already be some existing code for making an optimised regex to match a given set of fixed strings, again, IDK.

To do it yourself, the simplest thing would be to sort your strings and look for common prefixes / suffixes.  (`(afoo|bbaz|c)bar.com`).  Looking for common strings in the middle is less easy.  You might want to look at algorithms used for lossless data compression for finding redundancy.

You'd ideally want to spot cases where you could use a `foo[a-d]` range instead of a `foo(a|b|c|d)`, and various other things.